# How to remove the line in intervalmarker using Jfreechart?

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart

In the following code please tell me how to remove the line in IntervalMarker using Jfreechart?

```
IntervalMarker target1 = new IntervalMarker(85,111);
GradientPaintTransformer t1 = new StandardGradientPaintTransformer(GradientPaintTransformType.VERTICAL);
target1.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0.0F, 0.0F,new Color(189,227,208), 0.0F, 0.0F, new Color(186,214,231)));
target1.setGradientPaintTransformer(t1);                                              
xyplot.addRangeMarker(target1,Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
target1.setOutlineStroke(new BasicStroke(0));
```

Or

```
target1.setOutlineStroke(null);
```

Update to show results

Null `OutlineStroke`

[image]

`BasicStroke(0)`

[image]

Default

[image]

Comment: @Ree many you could add a screen shot, I checked that the above code works but it's hard to tell if you are seeing a border for the marker or the  graticule

Comment: i have added a screen shot ... pls refer that and do the needful